# Validar varios inputs

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

tengo la siguiente duda: por ejemplo en mi formulario de pedido quiero hacer esto: tengo un input en donde ingreso la cantidad de servicios ej 1,2,3,4 etc. en otro el precio y a traves de otro quisiera fijar el impuesto y en otro mostrar el precio con impuesto pero me gustaria saber si se puede hacer de manera automatica, es decir, que al momento de ingresar la cantidad esta se vaya multiplicando por el precio mas el impuesto y se muestre automaticamente en el ultimo input es decir tendria 4 inputs. Saludos, espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo con con algo asi podrias salirte

```
    Servicios: <input type="text" id="services" value="1" onchange="makeCalcs()"/><br>
    Precio: <input type="text" id="price" value="0" onchange="makeCalcs()"/><br>
    Impuesto: <input type="text" id="iva" value="21" onchange="makeCalcs()"/><br>
    Total: <input type="text" id="total" value="0"/><br>

    <script>
        function makeCalcs() {
            var services = document.getElementById("services").value;
            var price = document.getElementById("price").value;
            var iva = document.getElementById("iva").value;

            document.getElementById("total").value = services * price + (iva / 100 * (services * price));
        }
    </script>
```

Es bastante simple cada vez que edites uno de los campos el ultimo se actualizara con la información necesaria, ha esto le puedes añadir mas cosas como que no se permitan usar characteres/letras para que solo se usen números. Pero en principio haría su trabajo.